# Image moving to folder but not saving the row in database

Tags: php

Everything was working fine until i decided to add a new product and nothing works , the picture is uploading to the folder but the problem is coming from the move_uploaded_file function , the thing is the function is working and moving pictures but the code is not moving to the next instruction does anyone have an idea about this error ?

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    $productName   = $_POST['productName'];
    $quantity      = $_POST['quantity'];
    $rate          = $_POST['rate'];
    $brandName     = $_POST['brandName'];
    $categoryName  = $_POST['categoryName'];
    $genderName    = $_POST['genderName'];
    $sizeName      = $_POST['sizeName'];
    $productStatus = $_POST['productStatus'];
    $type = explode('.', $_FILES['productImage']['name']);
    $type = $type[count($type) - 1];
    $url  = '../assests/images/stock/' . uniqid(rand()) . '.' . $type;
    if (in_array($type, ['gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'JPG', 'GIF', 'JPEG', 'PNG'])) {
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name'])) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name'], $url)) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO product (product_name, product_image, brand_id, categories_id, quantity, price, active, status,gender_id,size_id,description,dateadded,discount)
                VALUES ('$productName', '$url', '$brandName', '$categoryName', '$quantity', '$rate', '$productStatus', 1,'$genderName','$sizeName')";
                if ($connect->query($sql) === true) {
                    echo "<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'> //not showing me this
        alert('Product added !');
        window.location.replace(\"http://localhost/stock/product.php\");
        </SCRIPT>";
                } else {
                    $valid['success']  = false;
                    $valid['messages'] = "Error while adding the members";
                }
            } else {
                echo "lool";
            }
        }
    }
    $connect->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: You probably have errors in your sql statement, you are not looking for them in your code. Insert and values do not match in terms of number of arguments

Comment: Can you give an error message?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the variable $connect declared anywhere in your code. It is possible that you have error reporting disabled and the script dies on

```
if ($connect->query($sql) === true) {
```

because $connect is undefined?